# Unit Test methods that contain a mediator using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mediator

I am currently unit testing a university register system, while it always has error when a method I am going to test contains a mediator which will contact to the University with served as a mediator. Is there any ideas of how to test this method?

The method is:

```
public void SelectCourse(List<Course> courses)
    {
        if (this.IsFullTime)
        {
            while (_CurrentCourses.Count < LEAST_NUM_OF_COURSES_FULLTIME)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                byte[] b = new byte[1];
                rand.NextBytes(b);
                int i = rand.Next(courses.Count);
                Course c = courses.ToArray()[i];
                ((University)mediator).RegisterStudentForCourse(this, c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (_CurrentCourses.Count < LEAST_NUM_OF_COURSES_PARTTIME)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                byte[] b = new byte[1];
                rand.NextBytes(b);
                int i = rand.Next(courses.Count);
                Course c = courses.ToArray()[i];

                // I always //has unit test error with this line!!:
                ((University)mediator).RegisterStudentForCourse(this, c);
            }
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("Student: "
                                 + this.Name 
                                 + ", with student number: (" 
                                 + this.StudentNumber 
                                 +  ") registered.");
    }
```

Comment: With [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), you could insert a mock `University` object at runtime for unit test. A comparison of mock frameworks is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use

Comment: @ArunMahapatra dependency injection isn't strictly necessary to use mock objects in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I would Mock a University object in the tests and inject it into the class that holds these functions. Remember: you're attempting to test a UNIT of code.. not a whole chain of functionality as would be the case during integration tests.

Also.. I would refactor this.. I know this isn't what you've asked for.. however it could make testing much easier and bug finding less messy:

```
public ClassThatHousesTheseFunctions(IUniversity university) {
    this._university = university;
}

public void SelectCourse(List<Course> courses) {
    if (this.IsFullTime) {
        performCourseSelection(courses, LEAST_NUM_OF_COURSES_FULLTIME);
    }
    else {
        performCourseSelection(courses, LEAST_NUM_OF_COURSES_PARTTIME);
    }       
}

private void performCourseSelection(IList<Course> courses, int leastNumberOfCourses) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    while (courses.Count < leastNumberOfCourses) {
        int i = rand.Next(courses.Count);
        Course c = courses.ToArray()[i];
        _university.RegisterStudentForCourse(this, c);
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("Student: " + this.Name + ", with student number: (" + this.StudentNumber + ") registered.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me! I also noticed that I can use mock object to mock the University. And I search on Web for tutorial all day... I always get an error about the mock object. Let me show you an example: if I have a class called "Course", and in "Course" I have a method called "HasRequirement" return bool value. How can I mock this "HasRequirement" method so that in my unit test I can use the mocked HasRequirement to directly assign its value?